# How to set limitations for excel file with xlsx writer

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to generate an excel using python xlsxwriter module with the header, so that others can fill data in it. I am able to generate excel but, I want to restrict the user to enter only 5digits in a column. How to achieve this? 
Even I set column width, it is not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Excel Data Validation option in XlsxWriter.

See the [Working with Data Validation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_data_validation.html) section of the docs and this [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_data_validate.html).